# How to resolve bundle shorthand to directory path?

Tags: symfony

From a bundle shorthand string like `"AcmeExampleBundle"` is there a Symfony service I can use to resolve this to the directory path to that bundle's root, e.g. `"/path/to/site/src/acme/ExampleBundle"`

I need to do this for any bundle, without knowing in advance what the bundle is in advance, or if it even exists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `AcmeExampleBundle.php` class extends the [Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Bundle\Bundle](http://api.symfony.com/2.0/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/Bundle/Bundle.html) base class which provides a [getPath() method](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/Bundle/Bundle.php#L121). You can use this method to get the bundle directory path. It returns the bundle absolute path as a string.

If your real need is to **locate** a given resource in your bundle, you can use the [`kernel` service](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/KernelInterface.php) which provides a [locateResource()](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/KernelInterface.php#L126) method that returns the given resource file path.

**Example:**

```
$path = $container->get('kernel')->locateResource('@AcmeExampleBundle/path/to/your/file.xxx');
```

Comment: Thanks, although I meant for any bundle, not knowing what that bundle is in advance. Will add to my question.

Comment: If you want to do it for all your bundles, $container->getParameter('kernel.bundles'); gives you an array of 'bundleName' => 'bundleClass' array/key values through which you can iterate.